# connect to azure service bus client from react app

Tags: reactjs, azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I need help to understand if one can connect to Azure service bus client from a React application and still send and receive messages to and from the queue.

I did not come across any examples on the internet where one is calling an Azure service bus from React code. I tried the following code in Node.js and it is working fine. If I try to use the same code in a React component, it fails when trying to send the message to the queue, producing a time out in the console.

```
    import * as asb from "@azure/service-bus";

    const serviceBus = new asb.ServiceBusClient(<connectionStringSender>);
    const sender = serviceBus.createSender(<inputQueue>);
    await sender.sendMessages({
        body: "Hello",
        applicationProperties: { "my-property": "my-value" },
        messageId:123,
    });
    console.log("Message sent");
    await sender.close();


    const serviceBusRecevier = new asb.ServiceBusClient(<connectionStringReceiver>);
    const receiver = serviceBusRecevier.createReceiver(<outputQueue>);
    console.log("Waiting for messages...");
    const messages = await receiver.receiveMessages(5, { maxWaitTimeInMs: 10000 });
    for (const message of messages) {
        console.log(`Message Received: ${message.body}`);
        await receiver.completeMessage(message);
    }
```

Comment: I can send and receive messages to Azure Service Bus Queue with the React app as [this](https://i.imgur.com/ovyeQhG.png), without any timeout issue.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the below React js code to send and receive messages to the Azure Service Bus Queue.

**Code:**

**src/components/MessageSender.js** :

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function MessageSender() {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState('');

  const sendMessage = async () => {
    try {
      await fetch('/send-message', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ message }),
      });

      setMessage('');
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Send Message</h2>
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Enter message"
        value={message}
        onChange={(e) => setMessage(e.target.value)}
      />
      <button onClick={sendMessage}>Send</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default MessageSender;
```

**src/components/MessageReceiver.js** :

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

function MessageReceiver() {
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const receiveMessages = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch('/receive-messages');
        const data = await response.json();
        setMessages(data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    };

    receiveMessages();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Received Messages</h2>
      <ul>
        {messages.map((message, index) => (
          <li key={index}>{message}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

export default MessageReceiver;
```

**src/App.js** :

```js
import React from 'react';
import MessageSender from './components/MessageSender';
import MessageReceiver from './components/MessageReceiver';

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <MessageSender />
      <MessageReceiver />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**server.js** :

```js
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const { ServiceBusClient } = require('@azure/service-bus');

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());

const connectionString = '<servicebus-queue-connec-string>';
const queueName = '<Queue-name>';
const serviceBusClient = new ServiceBusClient(connectionString);

app.post('/send-message', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const sender = serviceBusClient.createSender(queueName);
    const messageBody = req.body.message;

    await sender.sendMessages({
      body: messageBody,
    });

    await sender.close();
    res.status(200).send('Message sent successfully');
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).send('Error sending message');
  }
});

app.get('/receive-messages', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const receiver = serviceBusClient.createReceiver(queueName);

    const messages = await receiver.receiveMessages(5, { maxWaitTimeInMs: 10000 });

    await receiver.close();

    res.status(200).json(messages.map((message) => message.body));
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).send('Error receiving messages');
  }
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});
```

**Output** :

It runs successfully as below,

[image]

Then, I send a message to the Azure Service Bus Queue from Postman like below,

I set this to **POST** with the above **output URL**, and kept it for sending messages that I want to send in the **Body** as **JSON** and Click on **Send**,

[image]

I received the above message in my Service Bus Queue in Azure Portal as below,

[image]

Then, I sent another **GET** request to receive the sent messages in **Postman** like below,

I got my two messages which I sent to the Azure Service Bus with the React app below,

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response. Our project requirement is to connect to azure service bus from React application instead of connecting through node JS, is it possible to connect azure service bus directly from React application